# Not able to open XLS returned as attachment via Django view

Tags: django, excel, http, mime-types

I'm using [xlwt](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlwt) to generate an Excel file which I'm returning as an attachment in the HttpResponse in a Django view.

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def my_view(request):
    ...
    workbook = xlwt.Workbook(encoding='utf-8')
    #write my workbook data here
    workbook.save(#absolute_path_here)

    response = HttpResponse(mimetype='application/vnd.ms-excel')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=worksheet.xls'
    return response
```

The file is saved to the path I specify and I can open the file correctly from disk and the data is present. However, when I attempt to open the file using Excel from the file download prompt, I'm greeted with:

[image]

[caption]
The file you are trying to open 'worksheet.xls', is in a different format than specified by the file extension. Verify that the file is not corrupted and is from a trusted source before opening the file. Do you want to open the file now?

and the Excel file has no data. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi. Using mimetype='application/xls' works fine for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The django HttpResponse is a file-like object (it provides write, flush ... methods see [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponse.write)). As a consequence, you can pass it directly to the save method of the Workbook.

```
import xlwt
wb = xlwt.Workbook()
...
...
response = HttpResponse(mimetype='application/vnd.ms-excel')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=your-file.xls'
wb.save(response)
return response
```

Comment: Works perfectly. I hadn't thought to pass the response as the content for the Workbook to write. Thanks!

Comment: Awesomeness. I'm definitely starring favoriting this post!

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the content of the file to `HttpResponse`, otherwise you are sending an empty reponse (no data); which is why you get that error.

```
import xlwt
wb = xlwt.Workbook()
# your code
content = StringIO.StringIO()
wb.save(content) # "File" is written
response = HttpResponse(content.getvalue(),
                        mimetype='application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=utf-8')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=worksheet.xls'
return response
```

Also, it is always good to pass the character set along with the mime type.